# Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have been working on a NodeJS project which uses PostgreSQL database. 
I am trying to implement migration to the database. Also, using Sequelize. After setting up the migration folder and config, it throws error while running db:migrate

The error is:
"Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0"

Comment: // with uri
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/db_name')

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Solution for me was based on what I had set for my `NODE_ENV` variable.

`echo $NODE_ENV`

If you do not have anything set for that variable, try setting it with the following:

`export NODE_ENV=development`

If a value *is* present, make sure you have an entry in your config file for *that* value. For me, I like to use `local`. So I had to update my config to this:

```
{
 local: {
  username: 'root',
  password: null,
  database: 'database_dev',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres'
  },
 development: {
  username: 'root',
  password: null,
  database: 'database_dev',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres'
  },
  test: {
  username: 'root',
  password: null,
  database: 'database_test',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres'
 },
 production: {
  username: 'root',
  password: null,
  database: 'database',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres'
 }
}
```

Comment: Where do I find this config file? I install sequelize from npm in a node.js project and I don't know where it is

Comment: @Mitro: If you are using the Sequelize CLI, I *think* it generates those files for you. Either way, take a look at the docs here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html

These should help explain the files that you will need in order to run migrations. If you're still having trouble, try opening a new question.

Comment: set export NODE_ENV=development
  this needs to be set in ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc in case of linux

Comment: alternatively you can use **--env** to specify an entry from config,
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:status --config "config.json" --env "development"`

Answer (score 16):

I was facing this error, as it turns out, because of typescipt's transformation/compilation.

A little background: I am using sequelize in a typescript project. And the database config file was in a `database.ts` file.

```js
const config = {
    development: {
        username: env.PG_USERNAME,
        password: env.PG_PASSWORD,
        database: 'sample_db',
        host: env.PG_HOST,
        port: env.PG_PORT,
        dialect: 'postgres',
    },
    test: {
        username: env.PG_USERNAME,
        password: env.PG_PASSWORD,
        database: 'sample_db',
        host: env.PG_HOST,
        port: env.PG_PORT,
        dialect: 'postgres',
    },
    production: {
        username: env.PG_USERNAME,
        password: env.PG_PASSWORD,
        database: 'sample_db',
        host: env.PG_HOST,
        port: env.PG_PORT,
        dialect: 'postgres',
    },
};

export default config;
```

In `.sequelizerc` file, I was pointing to the transpiled version of the `database.ts` file i.e. the `dist/config/database.js` file. As shown below:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    config: path.resolve('dist', 'config', 'database.js'),
    ...
};
```

But after inspecting the transpiled version of the `database.ts` file, i noticed that the config was exported as:

```
module.exports.default = config
```

But `sequelize` is expecting the config to be at `module.exports`.

So, I modified the `database.ts` file by appending this one line to the end of the file and that resolved it for me.

```
...

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 12):

Check the dialect once.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
// Option 1: Passing parameters separately
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Check your config file (env names)

```json
{
  development: {
    username: 'root',
    password: null,
    database: 'database_development',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  },
  test: {
    username: 'root',
    password: null,
    database: 'database_test',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  },
  production: {
    username: 'root',
    password: null,
    database: 'database_production',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I got same error and I saw this mistake in the code.

```
  title: {
    type: Sequelize,
    allowNull: false,
  },
```

Changed my code with this and problem is solved:

```
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have missed **.env file** in your project

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I wasn't pointing to the config file properly. It said "successfully loaded" but I wasn't pointing to the right file.

It should say "Loaded configuration file "[some path]/config.js"."

Answer (score 2):

In my case issue was the way I was exporting config from config.ts
`export const = {}` did not work
but `module.exports` worked:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME_DEVELOPMENT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  },
  test: {
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME_DEVELOPMENT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  },
  production: {
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME_DEVELOPMENT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After pulling my hair out for a couple hours, I realized I was doing `cd src; node app.js` when really I was supposed to do `node src/app.js`... Gooooooodness

Comment: This was my issue as well. I was using PM2 to manage an app and I (lazily) started the app via console by scolling through previous command strings - but I wasn't in the app's root directory when I executed the pm2 start command and this was the error I received even though the path to the app in the command string was absolute.

Answer (score 2):

After reading through all the answers and possible solutions to problems people had and nothing worked for me here is another additional solution for an environment that uses:

- **Typescript** (Having the sequelize config in .ts)
- **Sequelize**

Problem: **Not being able to run "sequelize db:migrate"** (getting the error from this thread) **due to sequelize not getting access to the .env file and cannot properly read the config**

Example config

```
    config: any = {
        "development": {
        "username": dbUser,
        "password": dbPassword,
    ...
    module.exports = config
```

**dbUser** is undefined for Sequelize

1. Create a ".sequelizerc" file in the root of your project and give it the path to the already built .js config file:

```
    const path = require('path');
    module.exports = {
        'config': path.resolve('./dist', 'src/config/config.js')
    };
```

2. In your config file add

```
    module.exports = config
```

as sequelize does not like ***export default config*** (as mentioned above). I have both types of exports.

3. Install the dotenv-cli (I did it as a dev dependency, but globally should work fine as well)
4. Run the migration command while suppling the .env file with:

   ***npx dotenv -e /path/to/.env sequelize db:migrate***

Also had to make sure my NODE_ENV is set to development:

***export NODE_ENV=development***

Answer (score 1):

I had a `config.js` file from a previous project with a non-standard value for my environment.

It was called `current`.

I changed it to `development` and the error went away.

```
const main = require('./main');

module.exports = {
  development: { // this was set to `current` in my case, and it was causing the error
    username: main.db.user,
    password: main.db.password,
    database: main.db.name,
    host: main.db.host,
    port: main.db.port || 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
  }
};
```

Comment: yes, same for me is important to verify the name, i was using stage and my env was staging, so thanks to this solution i realized what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to add the dialect to your config? 
see: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

if you have not setup any .env variables before running your `npm server`

You are likely to get that error. so each time you restart app for changes.
you will have to export again

```
export DATABASE_URL=<your-db-url>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused if there is an error in your model schema.

I had:

```
middle_name: {
    type: Sequelize.Sequelize,
    allowNull: false,
}
```

Which should had been:

```
middle_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I declared config.js like as:

```
module.exports = {
  production: {
    database: process.env.DB_PROD_DATABASE,
    username: process.env.DB_PROD_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PROD_PASSWORD,
    options: {
      host: process.env.DB_PROD_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PROD_PORT,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      define: {
        paranoid: true,
        timestamp: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: false
      }
    }
  },
  development: {
    database: process.env.DB_DEV_DATABASE || 'database_name',
    username: process.env.DB_DEV_USERNAME || 'user_name', 
    password: process.env.DB_DEV_PASSWORD || 'pass', 
    host: process.env.DB_DEV_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.DB_DEV_PORT || 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    define: {
      paranoid: true,
      timestamp: true,
      freezeTableName: true,
      underscored: false
    }
  }
}
```

But it should be like as:

```
module.exports = {
  production: {
    database: process.env.DB_PROD_DATABASE,
    username: process.env.DB_PROD_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PROD_PASSWORD,
    options: {
      host: process.env.DB_PROD_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PROD_PORT,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      define: {
        paranoid: true,
        timestamp: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: false
      }
    }
  },
  development: {
    database: 'database_name',
    username: 'user_name', 
    password: 'pass', 
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    define: {
      paranoid: true,
      timestamp: true,
      freezeTableName: true,
      underscored: false
    }
  }
}
```

without `process.env.DB_DEV_DATABASE || 'database_name'` eg.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error then,you have to add additional argument after **password_for_rootUser** in form of object and need to specify these property according to your RDBMS

```
var Sequilize=require('sequelize');
var connection =new Sequilize('db_name','root_user_name','password_for_rootUser',{
    host:'localhost',
    dialect:'mysql'|'mariadb'|'sqlite'|'postgress'|'mssql',
    pool:{
        max:5,
        min:0,
        idle:10000
    },
//for sqlite only
storage:path/to/database.sqlite


});


var Article=connection.define('tableName',{
    title:Sequilize.STRING, // your cloumn name with data type
    body:Sequilize.TEXT    // your cloumn name with data type
});

connection.sync();
```

hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by running this command

```
export NODE_ENV=development; npx sequelize db:migrate
```

cheers!

Comment: You can not enter that as a command, you should be more clear and please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to uncomment the `DB_CONNECTION` value from `.env` which is   used to establish postgreSQL connection in my code

Answer (score 0):

use below code in config/config.js to load env

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

my .sequelizerc

```
module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'sequelize.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('src', 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src', 'migrations')
};
```

and config/sequelize.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

export default {
    development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
        dialectOptions: {
            bigNumberStrings: true
        }
    },
    test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    },
    production: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
        dialectOptions: {
            bigNumberStrings: true,
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was using "ES6 module system" and in package.json I forgot to add:

```
{
    "type": "module",
    ...
}
```

The "config.js" export was exporting the object inside "default" property because I was exporting `export default configDB;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted the dialect being passed as a prop to a function.
As a workaround I used template literals.

```
export function connectDB(database, dialect, logging = false) {
  const connectionConfig = {
    server: process.env[`LOCAL_${dialect.toUpperCase()}_SERVER`],
    database: database,
    username: process.env[`LOCAL_${dialect.toUpperCase()}_USERNAME`],
    password: process.env[`LOCAL_${dialect.toUpperCase()}_PASSWORD`],
    host: process.env[`LOCAL_${dialect.toUpperCase()}_HOST`],
    port: process.env[`LOCAL_${dialect.toUpperCase()}_PORT`],
    dialect: `${dialect.toLowerCase()}`,
    logging: logging,
  }
  return new Sequelize(connectionConfig)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating db in Sequelize ORM, I try to create sequelize db:migrate. I got this:

> ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Eventually, I found a solution that worked for me:

```bash
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env development
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: this happens when the config file is unable to read your database credentials. SO if your credentials are stored in an .env file, your config file is unable to reach your .env file(or your credentials are not present in the env file). So I had to add relative path of .env file in config file. something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../.env') });
```

**replace `../../.env` with your relative path of .env w.r.t. config file**
So your env file should look something like this:

```
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
DB_NAME=your_db_name
DB_HOST=localhost //if you are running on local machine
DB_DIALECT=postgres //change according to your dialect
DB_PORT=5432  //optional
```