# Sequelize 'Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0'

Tags: node.js, error-handling, sequelize.js

I need to run third party application in node.js environment but Sequelize throws 'Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0'
I've found similar topic here [Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694157/dialect-needs-to-be-explicitly-supplied-as-of-v4-0-0) but 'export NODE_ENV=development' doesn't work and I can not find Sequelize config file.
How can I fix this error?

Here is code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const scheme = require('./scheme');

const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, {

dialect: 'sqlite',
storage: 'db.sqlite3',

operatorsAliases: { $and: Op.and },

logging: false
});

scheme(sequelize);
sequelize.sync();

module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;
module.exports.models = sequelize.models;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You simply supply the dialect when you initialize sequelize;

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: // pick one of 'mysql','sqlite','postgres','mssql',
});
```

Comment: Yes, and you have passed two parameters before the options for dialect. Where as three are required. See my post

Answer (score 7):

Node cannot find your environment to load in the config file.

You can easily fix by running this

```
 export NODE_ENV=development; npx sequelize db:migrate
```

This should export to NODE_ENV the environment needed to run it.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = {};

const DB = 'users';
const USER = 'user';
const PASSWORD = 'password';
const HOST = 'host';
const DIALECT = 'postgres';
const PORT = 5432;

const CONNECTION = new Sequelize(
    DB,
    USER, 
    PASSWORD, 
    {
        host: HOST,
        dialect: DIALECT,
        port: PORT,
    }
)

module.exports.CONNECTION = CONNECTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have solved the problem. But I faced the same issue.
My issue had happened due to the name change of the config file that is auto generated by the sequelize-cli. So what I eventually did was, I created a .sequelizerc file in the project root folder and include following content.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'database.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('db', 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('db', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('db', 'migrations')
};
```

Make sure to change the arguments according to your folder structure of the project.
A comprehensive explanation has on the sequelize documentation page.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html