# Error when adding config.name to const sequelize = new Sequelize()

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.email,
    config.password,
    config
);
```

There is no error.

But when I add only config.user I get an error

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize 'Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397401/sequelize-dialect-needs-to-be-explicitly-supplied-as-of-v4-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `dialect` to the config,
also see: [Sequelize Manual - Dialects](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/dialects.html)