# Sequelize db migrate issue

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using node, express and sequelize where when i run sequelize db:migrate am getting the following issue,

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 13.2.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.2]

Loaded configuration file "server/config/config.json".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
```

Config file for db authentication is,

```
{
  "dev": {
    "username": "user_1",
      "password": "pass",
      "database": "todos_dev",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "postgres",
      "operatorsAliases": false
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "operatorsAliases": false,
    "dialectOptions": {
      "bigNumberStrings": true
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "operatorsAliases": false
  }
}
```

[image: Roles and permissions available in db]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694157/dialect-needs-to-be-explicitly-supplied-as-of-v4-0-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sequlize is not able to get **NODE_ENV** means it is not able to decide which authentication detail it should use, you need to define that  using

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```

or when you do config for DB connection you can check it as  -

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: I added export NODE_ENV=development in **bashrc** of Ubuntu. It worked, Thank you.