# SEQUELIZE - db:migrate "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, migration, sequelize-typescript

**Hello All,**

Iǘe been try to apply the db:migrate in Typescript with NodeJS, PostgreSQL, by command line in the Kali Linux and it has been not possible because the config,JSON says me that there is a statement outside a module, print screen below.

config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgBeD.png)

db command line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIYCe.png)

I've tried follow the oficial documentation, and I also have tried solving with thread from stackoverflow below:
[Sequelize db migrate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451158/sequelize-db-migrate-issue)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Completing the above information, follow the  commands and archives:

sequelize db:migrate ==>

sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 18.13.0, CLI: 6.6.1, ORM: 6.33.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
== create-table.test: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot use import statement outside a module

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

my config.json==>
{
  "development": {
    "username": "lovelystay",
    "password": "101010",
    "database": "lovelystay",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },