# Sequelize Node.js What is the correct syntax of super constructor objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing an issue in my Node.js app, where the log says "Invalid shorthand initializer". However, I checked online, and the official syntax to declare super constructor objects, is by doing `objectname = {property: 'X'};` 
However, for the `options = {` line, it gives me this error message. 
What am I doing wrong here? How is options declared correctly?

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = class Database extends Sequelize {
    constructor() {
        super({
            database : process.env.DatabaseName,
            username : process.env.DatabaseUsername,
            password : process.env.DatabasePassword,
            options = {
                host: process.env.DatabaseHost,
                dialect: "mysql"
            }
        })
    };

    Authenticate() {
        this
            .authenticate()
            .then(() => console.log(`Logged in to Database ${process.env.DatabaseName}!`))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
};
```

My dependencies in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "abort-controller": "^3.0.0",
    "asynckit": "^0.4.0",
    "callsites": "^3.1.0",
    "combined-stream": "^1.0.8",
    "delayed-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.20.2",
    "discord.js": "^13.3.1",
    "dot-prop": "^6.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "event-target-shim": "^5.0.1",
    "form-data": "^3.0.1",
    "is-obj": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "mime-db": "^1.51.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.34",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.6",
    "ow": "^0.27.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.12.0-alpha.1",
    "tr46": "^0.0.3",
    "ts-mixer": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "type-fest": "^1.4.0",
    "vali-date": "^1.0.0",
    "webidl-conversions": "^3.0.1",
    "whatwg-url": "^5.0.0",
    "ws": "^8.2.3"
}
```

Looking forward to your answers guys. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `options = {` -> `options : {`

Comment: If I change that to `:`, then the log says: `Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0`

Comment: This is [a different error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694157/dialect-needs-to-be-explicitly-supplied-as-of-v4-0-0). According to the answers given to the other question, seems like you don't need `options` property but directly supply the dialect in the main body of the object.

Comment: Oh yeah, strange, because on the official website of Sequelize, the very first example code is this: `var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'});`
Thanks mate :)

Comment: Yes, that passes another parameter which is an object, but not an object with `options`.

Comment: And in the API reference its `constructor(database: string, username: string, password: string, options: object)`
So why doesn't this qualify?

Comment: `database: string, username: string, password: string, options: object` describes *four parameters* - `database` which is a string, `username` which is a string, `password` which is a string, and `options` which is an object. It's not one object with four fields in it.

Comment: AH! I see it now... Thank you :)